# How to use __getattr__ to delegate methods to attribute?

Tags: python, composition, getattr

I have the following class:

```
class MyInt:
    def __init__(self, v):
        if type(v) != int:
            raise ValueError('value must be an int')
        self.v = v

    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        return getattr(self.v, attr)

i = MyInt(0)
print(i + 1)
```

I get the error: `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'MyInt' and 'int'`

Shouldn't `i.__add__(1)` be called? And shouldn't `__getattr__` be called when no such method is found in the `MyInt` class?

Comment: [In addition to bypassing any instance attributes in the interest of correctness, implicit special method lookup generally also bypasses the `__getattribute__()` method even of the object’s metaclass](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-lookup)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`__getattr__` cannot be used to generate other magic methods. You'll need to implement all of them individually.

When the Python language internals look up magic methods like `__add__`, they completely bypass `__getattr__`, `__getattribute__`, and the instance dict. The lookup goes roughly like

```
def find_magic_method(object, method_name):
    for klass in type(object).__mro__:
        if method_name in klass.__dict__:
            return klass.__dict__[method_name]
    raise AttributeError
```

If you want to see the exact lookup procedure, it's `_PyObject_LookupSpecial` in [`Objects/typeobject.c`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Objects/typeobject.c#l1244).

If you're wondering why Python does this, there are a lot of magic methods for which it would be really awkward or impossible to do what you were expecting. For example, Python couldn't possibly use `__getattribute__` to look up `__getattribute__`, as that would cause infinite recursion with no base case.

Comment: The difference between the real lookup and that python code is that the above python code could be manipulated using meta-classes to provide a custom `__dict__`, while the real lookup bypasses even the metaclass and accesses the `__dict__` mapping via the direct field in the underlying C structure.

Comment: That's a long file, could you give me a line number or function name please?

Comment: @JonMcClung: The link goes right to the function, and I did say the function name is `_PyObject_LookupSpecial `. Most of the helpers it relies on are in the same file, so you should be able to find them with Ctrl-F.

Comment: My bad. I scrolled around before it finished loading, causing it to end up in the wrong place.